# WCF REST service returning JSONP no error but no data either

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

I can see the data in the Sources tab in Chrome which shows json?callback=jQuery1324235... if I click that item I can see my JSON string.

I'm not getting the cross domain error or any error in Chrome.  My ajax is the following, the error section just returns Success as the status.  The debugger never stops in the success block though.

```
 $.ajax({
  cache:false,
  type: 'GET',
  async: false,
  timeout: 60000,
      data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: 'http://urlsvc/json',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {   
var test = data;
    $.each(data,function(i,j){
    list += "<h2 class='name'>" + j.TraitName + "</h2><p class='category'>" + j.Category + "</p><p class='desc'>" + j.Description + "</p>";
    });                     
},
  error: function (xhr) {
         err += xhr.statusText;
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#list1').html(list);
  }
        });
```

Comment: What was http code of response ?

Comment: The http code was 200

Comment: and did wrapper function name in response matched parameter in query string or no ?

Comment: ie if query string has `callback=jQuery1324235` was response `jQuery1324235(....json payload here...)` or no ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see the response, is it in the XHR?  I don't have a wrapper function, I didn't think I needed one the way I'm doing it.

Comment: you know how jsonp works, right? you DO need it. not a function, a function call. Also you saying you see response in source tab. post it here togther with link.

Comment: Did you try to print out error detials, like  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) ?

Comment: I used xhr.statusText and looked at other values during debugging they all seemed null.  I didn't know about thrownError though.  It stops in error: but xhr.statusText is success.  Also I'm still pretty new to jQuery.  As far as a function call I tried putting ?callback=? at the end of the url, I read that it creates a dynamic function, I'm not sure how to use that exactly though.

Comment: Just had a chance to try it with thrownError, it says jQuery1234235 was not called.  So, that's my real issue how do I call it?

Comment: I also get ajaxoptions parseerror, so I assume something is wrong with my ajax code?

Comment: No vittore the response doesn't contain the function, it's just pure JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  It was my service, I missed the bindingConfiguration attribute in the web.config.  Thanks everyone!